# Run a Script Each time a table is modified

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, batch-file

I have created a batch script which prints information on the table into a label and saves it into **pdf**. At the moment, I am giving the script a number, which is the `ItemCode` and it prints out the rest of the information in the table.

Well now I'm going much further, my goal is to run the script each time the table is modified, or a new row is added or even if a single field is modified. When this happens it would check which row has been modified and It would run the script with the ItemCode which has been modified.

Been looking for something similar to this but couldn't find anything precise enough, so any help would be nice!

Comment: Can't you just use triggers? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger

Comment: I could. I have to say I'm not very familiar with them. But how could I check what row has been modified and get the field "ItemCode" to use it as a parameter in the script?

Comment: You could use a trigger as has been suggested and inserted.ItemCode will give you the parameter you require. However, this will severely impact the performance of your update statement as it will have to wait for the batch file to complete. Better off passing this off to something else to process, be that another table with a scheduled job or a messaging system such as Service Broker.

Comment: I know ItemCode will give me the parameter i need. But as far I understand, in this case the trigger would run the script every time the table is been modified. But doesn´t tell me what row or field has been modified, or does it?

Comment: The special inserted table gives you access to the record that has been updated. So SELECT inserted.ItemCode gives you the ItemCode that was updated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Ben You got that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code below is part of a trigger I am using. It writes old values and new values into a special table to track all important changes. The updated_idx is send with the SQL command to tell, what user is doing it.:

```
USE [Demo] -- database
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[update_Address]    Script Date: 26.07.2018 11:16:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[update_Address] ON [dbo].[Address] for UPDATE AS
    DECLARE @fieldname varchar(128) = '- empty -'
    DECLARE @newValue varchar(2048) = '- empty -'
    DECLARE @oldValue varchar(2048)= '- empty -'
    DECLARE @Updated int = datediff(s,'01/01/1970',SYSUTCDATETIME())
    DECLARE @Updated_IDX int = -1
    DECLARE @ID int = -1
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Address_id, Updated_IDX FROM inserted
    OPEN db_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID, @Updated_IDX -- this takes the current id 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON


        If UPDATE([ZipCode])
        BEGIN
            SELECT @OldValue=b.ZipCode, @NewValue=a.ZipCode FROM inserted a, deleted b
            IF @NewValue <>  @OldValue
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO TransactionLog ([ID],[TableName],[Type],[FieldName],[newValue],[oldValue],[Updated],[Updated_IDX]) values (@ID,'Address','U','ZipCode',@newValue,@oldValue,@Updated,@Updated_IDX);
            END
        END

        If UPDATE([City])
        BEGIN
            SELECT @OldValue=b.City, @NewValue=a.City FROM inserted a, deleted b
            IF @NewValue <>  @OldValue
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO TransactionLog ([ID],[TableName],[Type],[FieldName],[newValue],[oldValue],[Updated],[Updated_IDX]) values (@ID,'Address','U','City',@newValue,@oldValue,@Updated,@Updated_IDX);
            END
        END


        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID, @Updated_IDX
    End
    CLOSE db_cursor
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Could I ask you to explain what does the line "DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Address_id, Updated_IDX FROM inserted" and the 3 lines under! Thank you!

Comment: It takes the values address_id and updated_idx from the row, that is going to be updated and stores the values to the variables ID and Updated_idx. IN my database the column address_id is a unique value for each record and the column Updated_idx is a number referenced to table user, that helps me to know, who is doing the changes.